# How do I update an object in the ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, uwp

I try to update the object inside the ObservableCollection collection, the collection seems to be updated. But in the View itself, the data remains the same...

```
Item current = Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == item.ID);
current = current.Remained = current.Count - current.InStock;
```

An anchor on the page

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Count}" Foreground="#E5FFFFFF" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding InStock, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#E5FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="InStock_TextChanged"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Remained}" Foreground="#E5FFFFFF" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

When you enter in a string In Stock, the calculation should be carried out and immediately the result is displayed in the string Retained..

Comment: does the class 'Item' implement the interface 'INotifyPropertyChanged' ?

Comment: Yes, it is implemented. And I even catch property changes, but the View is still not updated.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i already asked that. he says he has implemented this and even catches the propertychanged-events

Comment: @D.J. Sorry about that. hi Максим Шалашов could you share a mini sample that could  reproduce this issue ?

Comment: @МаксимШалашов I feel like you aren't providing enough code for us. Id like to see how you are creating this observable collection and binding it to the view you are describing. Little confused.